# Link tag (<a>) in Python post requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to post a request to the [telegra.ph](http://telegra.ph) api (a simple online publishing tool). In order to edit the content of the page, I am using python `requests`. From the sample code I got from the api documentation, I so far have:

```
import requests

params = {
    'path': '/mypage',
    'title': 'My Title',
    'content':[{"tag":"p","children":["WHAT IS GOING ON"]}],
    'author_name': 'My Name',
    'author_url': None,
    'return_content': 'true'
}

url = 'https://api.telegra.ph/editPage'

r = requests.post(url, json=params)
r.raise_for_status()
response = r.json()
```

Very simple code, and it works fine. My issue is that I would now like to add a link to my content. I tried changing the tag from `"p"` to `"a"` but that results in no tags at all in the resulting page. Does anyone know what format they are using for their content, and how I can change the paragraph tag to a link tag?

Comment: please post a link to the original sample code, the link you have doesn't seem to go to any relevant documentation.

Comment: From the [api documentation](http://telegra.ph/api) in the **NodeElement** section it says `"a"` is supported and for **attrs**: " Attributes of the DOM element. Key of object represents name of attribute, value represents value of attribute. Available attributes: _href_, _src_."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to create a page with a link:

```
import requests

params = {
    'access_token': "",
    'path': '/mytestpage',
    'title': 'My Title',
    'content':[ {"tag":"p","children":["A link to Stackoverflow ",{"tag":"a","attrs":{"href":"http://stackoverflow.com/","target":"_blank"},"children":["http://stackoverflow.com"]}]} ],
    'author_name': 'My Name',
    'author_url': None,
    'return_content': 'true'
}

url = 'https://api.telegra.ph/createPage'

r = requests.post(url, json=params)
r.raise_for_status()
response = r.json()
print response
```

You should be able to do something similar for editPage.

Tip: You can use something like Postman or Chrome dev tools to figure what is being posted using the telegra.ph UI.